# How to hide toolbar of Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

Does anybody know how to automatically hide the toolbar (containing buttons "disconnect", "send keys" and "screen options") at top of the window of Chrome Remote Desktop? That toolbar covers many important things on screen like browser tags, very annoying.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is that 4 arrows thing that looks like an X next the the keyboard icon 
simply press it and you will get what you want ! :)
and you can zoom in and out by pinching the screen